# the previously created nodes are not deleted

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j script which is supposed to read data from a .csv file and create nodes based on the data available in this file. Here is the code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///names.csv' AS row
WITH row.Fname AS first, row.Lname AS last
MERGE (p:la {last: last})
MERGE (o:fi {first: first})
.
.
.
RETURN count(o);
```

The problem is that I want to delete the previously created nodes before executing these commands, so I added this line at the beginning of the above code:

```
MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n
```

but it doesn't seem to work and the previously created nodes are not deleted. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it did not work? After running that query, what does this return: `MATCH (n) RETURN COUNT(*)`

Comment: @cybersam I received an error stating that I'm missing `WITH` between 2 first commands, but should I just write `WITH`? Or I need something like `WITH *`?

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using? `WITH` should not be necessary.

Comment: @cybersam 4.0.3

Comment: I am also using 4.0.3, and I do not get that error.